# Flink stucked in Starting TaskManagers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are trying to run our flink application in our yarn cluster with the following settings:

Parallelism: 60

Job manager memory: 2g

Task manager memory: 2g

Task manager slots: 1

When we submit the job the following happens

```
2020-11-26 17:24:40,450 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Received 1 containers.
2020-11-26 17:24:40,456 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Received 1 containers with resource <memory:2048, vCores:10>, 1 pending container requests.
2020-11-26 17:24:40,461 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - TaskExecutor container_e352_1592997214849_1528083_01_000005 will be started on dlawsq.sample.com with TaskExecutorProcessSpec {cpuCores=10.0, frameworkHeapSize=128.000mb (134217728 bytes), frameworkOffHeapSize=128.000mb (134217728 bytes), taskHeapSize=537.600mb (563714445 bytes), taskOffHeapSize=0 bytes, networkMemSize=158.720mb (166429984 bytes), managedMemorySize=634.880mb (665719939 bytes), jvmMetaspaceSize=256.000mb (268435456 bytes), jvmOverheadSize=204.800mb (214748368 bytes)}.
2020-11-26 17:24:40,467 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Adding keytab hdfs://storagens1/user/user/.flink/application_1592997214849_1528083/user.keytab to the AM container local resource bucket
2020-11-26 17:24:41,259 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Creating container launch context for TaskManagers
2020-11-26 17:24:41,261 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Starting TaskManagers
2020-11-26 17:24:41,280 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Removing container request Capability[<memory:2048, vCores:10>]Priority[1].
2020-11-26 17:24:41,280 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Accepted 1 requested containers, returned 0 excess containers, 0 pending container requests of resource <memory:2048, vCores:10>.
2020-11-26 17:24:54,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    [] - Checkpoint triggering task Source: radcom_gi_v3 -> Flink Kafka Consumer -> (Column Reduction -> Timestamps/Watermarks, Map -> Sink: Dropped Messages HDFS Parquet Writer) (1/5) of job 2e127b83d14dcaa44baae146360169ed is not in state RUNNING but SCHEDULED instead. Aborting checkpoint.
2020-11-26 17:24:56,476 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Requesting new TaskExecutor container with resource WorkerResourceSpec {cpuCores=10.0, taskHeapSize=537.600mb (563714445 bytes), taskOffHeapSize=0 bytes, networkMemSize=158.720mb (166429984 bytes), managedMemSize=634.880mb (665719939 bytes)}. Number pending workers of this resource is 1.
2020-11-26 17:25:01,978 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Received 1 containers.
2020-11-26 17:25:01,979 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Received 1 containers with resource <memory:2048, vCores:10>, 1 pending container requests.
2020-11-26 17:25:01,979 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - TaskExecutor container_e352_1592997214849_1528083_01_000010 will be started on dlawsq.sample.com with TaskExecutorProcessSpec {cpuCores=10.0, frameworkHeapSize=128.000mb (134217728 bytes), frameworkOffHeapSize=128.000mb (134217728 bytes), taskHeapSize=537.600mb (563714445 bytes), taskOffHeapSize=0 bytes, networkMemSize=158.720mb (166429984 bytes), managedMemorySize=634.880mb (665719939 bytes), jvmMetaspaceSize=256.000mb (268435456 bytes), jvmOverheadSize=204.800mb (214748368 bytes)}.
2020-11-26 17:25:01,980 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Adding keytab hdfs://storagens1/user/user/.flink/application_1592997214849_1528083/user.keytab to the AM container local resource bucket
2020-11-26 17:25:02,024 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Creating container launch context for TaskManagers
2020-11-26 17:25:02,026 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Starting TaskManagers
2020-11-26 17:25:02,027 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Removing container request Capability[<memory:2048, vCores:10>]Priority[1].
2020-11-26 17:25:02,027 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Accepted 1 requested containers, returned 0 excess containers, 0 pending container requests of resource <memory:2048, vCores:10>.
2020-11-26 17:25:17,486 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnResourceManager                    [] - Requesting new TaskExecutor container with resource WorkerResourceSpec {cpuCores=10.0, taskHeapSize=537.600mb (563714445 bytes), taskOffHeapSize=0 bytes, networkMemSize=158.720mb (166429984 bytes), managedMemSize=634.880mb (665719939 bytes)}. Number pending workers of this resource is 1.
```

The behavior above goes on until the slot request timeout is reached then the NoResourceAvailable exception is encountered.

```
2020-11-26 17:29:34,419 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: source_gi_v3 -> Flink Kafka Consumer -> (Column Reduction -> Timestamps/Watermarks, Map -> Sink: Dropped Messages HDFS Parquet Writer) (1/5) (79c554d2a3ff14499262a6a5e852f846) switched from SCHEDULED to FAILED on not deployed.
org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not allocate the required slot within slot request timeout. Please make sure that the cluster has enough resources.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeWrapWithNoResourceAvailableException(DefaultScheduler.java:441) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.lambda$assignResourceOrHandleError$6(DefaultScheduler.java:422) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SchedulerImpl.lambda$internalAllocateSlot$0(SchedulerImpl.java:168) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$SingleTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:726) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$MultiTaskSlot.release(SlotSharingManager.java:537) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.SlotSharingManager$MultiTaskSlot.lambda$new$0(SlotSharingManager.java:432) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$forwardTo$21(FutureUtils.java:1120) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$Timeout.run(FutureUtils.java:1036) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:402) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:195) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152) ~[flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [flink-streaming-framework-1.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    ... 23 more
2020-11-26 17:29:34,440 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - Calculating tasks to restart to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0.
2020-11-26 17:29:34,441 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy [] - 12 tasks should be restarted to recover the failed task cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0. 
2020-11-26 17:29:34,443 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job  Aggregation (2e127b83d14dcaa44baae146360169ed) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
```

So far we've tried these things:

Lowering the Parallelism from 60 to 7

Increasing the task manager slots to 10

After these we still encounter the same error. Can someone advise on how to resolve the error we are encountering.

Comment: Try to set the parallelism for 1, make sure that you dont disable operators chain optimization, keep the slots in 10 and see what happens. Then you increase the parallelism and reduce the slot numbers step by step (between queries restarts). It is likely there is no sufficient slots for the operators. Besides that check if the TMs connect to the JM and the TMs are receiving the operators when you deploy the job.

Comment: Hi @Felipe, I tried your suggestion but it resulted to the same error. I suspect this might be a connection or access issue.

Comment: Check your `/etc/hosts` file and if the machines can connect to each other using ssh without password.